# Overlay 2 allEffects graphs

Tags: r, plot, overlay, effects, graphing

I have the following model

```
require(effects)

fit<-lme(x ~ y, data, random= ~1|item)
plot(allEffects(fit)

fit2<-lme(x ~ y, data2, random = ~1|item)
plot(allEffects(fit2)
```

How can I plot fit and fit2 overlaying?  I have tried the par(new=T), but it does not work. The graphs plot fine individually.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: provide some data, and what do you mean by overlay? At the very least show us an example of what you want your plot to look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a *very* nice way to do this.  I usually extract the information from the effects structure and plot it with ggplot (lattice would be possible too).

Here's an example:

```
library(effects)
library(nlme)
library(plyr)  ## utilities
```

Fit a model to the first and second half of one of the standard example data sets:

```
fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age, random = ~1|Subject,
          data = Orthodont[1:54,])
fm2 <- update(fm1, data = Orthodont[55:108,])
a1 <- allEffects(fm1)
a2 <- allEffects(fm2)
```

Extract the information from the `efflist` object.  This is the part that isn't completely general ... the hard part is getting out the predictor variable.

```
as.data.frame.efflist <- function(x) {
   ldply(x,
         function(z) {
           r <- with(z,data.frame(fit,
                                  var=variables[[1]]$levels,
                                  lower,upper))
           return(plyr::rename(r,setNames(z$variables[[1]]$name,"var")))
         })
}
```

For convenience, use `ldply` to put the results of both models together:

```
comb <- ldply(list(fm1=a1,fm2=a2),as.data.frame,.id="model")
```

Now plot:

```
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(comb,aes(age,fit,
               ymin=lower,ymax=upper,
               colour=model,fill=model))+
     geom_line()+
     geom_ribbon(alpha=0.2,colour=NA)+
     geom_rug(sides="b")
```

The rug plot component is a little silly here.

[image]